# PHP not properly inserting into the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm converting my code from extremely long GET statements (is that the correct word?) into separate files for each page. The code I'm about to show worked fine before I moved it to it's own file.

The page's full code is:

```
    <?
    require_once('./inc/glob_head.php');

    $database->openConnection();

    $listOfGamesQuery = $database->queryDB("SELECT * FROM mainSite_games");

    if (isset($_GET) && $_GET['action'] == 'deleteGame') 
    {
        $gameID = $_GET['gameID'];
        $database->queryDB("DELETE FROM mainSite_games WHERE id='$gameID'");
        redir('viewGames.php');
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET) && $_GET['action'] == 'editGame')
    {
        $gameID = $_GET['gameID'];
        $gameNameQry = $database->queryDB("SELECT gameName FROM mainSite_games WHERE id='$gameID'");
        while ($gameNameDta = $database->fetchArray($gameNameQry))
        { 
            $gameName = $gameNameDta['gameName'];
        }

        $gameDescQry = $database->queryDB("SELECT gameDesc FROM mainSite_games WHERE id='$gameID'");

        while ($gameDescDta = $database->fetchArray($gameDescQry))
        { 
            $gameDesc = $gameDescDta['gameDesc'];
        }
    ?>
    <form name="editGame" id="editGame" action="viewGames.php?action=processEdit&gameID=<? echo $gameID; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="gameName" value="<? echo stripslashes($gameName); ?>" /><br />
        <textarea name="gameDesc" class="span12" rows="10"><? echo stripslashes($gameDesc); ?></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submitEditGame" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
    <?
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET) && $_GET['action'] == 'processEdit')
    {
        $gameID = $_GET['gameID'];
        $gameName = $database->escapeString($_POST['gameName']);

        $gameDesc = $database->escapeString($_POST['gameDesc']);

        $database->queryDB("UPDATE mainSite_games SET gameName='$gameName' WHERE id='$gameID'");

        $database->queryDB("UPDATE mainSite_games SET gameDesc='$gameDesc' WHERE id='$gameID'");

        redir('viewGames.php');

    } else {
                    echo '<div class="contCont">';
                        echo '<table>';
                            echo '<thead>';
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<th>Game Name</th>';
                                    echo '<th>Delete</th>';
                                    echo '<th>Edit</th>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            echo '</thead>';
                            echo '<tbody>';
                                while ($listOfGames = $database->fetchAssoc($listOfGamesQuery)) {
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                        print '<td>' . stripslashes($listOfGames['gameName']) . '</td>';
                                        print '<td><a href="viewGames.php?action=deleteGame&gameID='.$listOfGames['id'].'">Delete</a></td>';
                                        print '<td><a href="viewGames.php?action=editGame&gameID='.$listOfGames['id'].'">Edit</a></td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                }
                            echo '</tbody>';
                        echo '</table>';
                     echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</body>';
    echo '</html>';
}
$database->closeConnection();
?>
```

glob_head just provides the database class, the database connection, the functions file requirement, and styling/page structure that is constant around the site. Having stated this, the $database calls are not mistakes, and are actually defined elsewhere.

Now the problem is, in the above code, the editGame elseif block pulls information from the database successfully, therefore I assume that it must be getting the information correctly. Now, when a user clicks submit, it'll take them to the next block, processEdit, and that for some reason makes the fields blank and sets the blank values in the database. I have no idea what's going on. Maybe this needs a fresh set of eyes? Thanks in advance.

*For your reference, the 'redir' calls are a custom function that uses javascript redirection instead of relying on headers. I find it cleaner, and possibly easier to use than changing the structure of the code.*

Comment: Ever heard of formatting your code?

Comment: @DarylGill I did format it. Is it not showing as such for you?..

Comment: I'm sorry how that may have come across. I see you did format your code, but it's a little muddled when looking over it. I have added some line breaks and formatted your PHP `while loops` for easier readability

Comment: @DarylGill Ah, sorry about that. I'll be sure to space it out in future questions.

Comment: Please research SQL injection, you've got some security issues there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting `METHOD="POST"` but looking at the `$_GET` superglobal variable. The `$_GET` variable is empty, because there is no GET submission being made.

Change all instances of `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` (or `$_POST`), or change `METHOD="POST"` to `"METHOD="GET"`.

Comment: Okay..first of all, thanks for your answer. I changed all GETS to REQUEST, and it works..but why? I used GET before, and it worked. Could you clarify?

Comment: If you submit with GET, the data gets put into the $_GET array. If you submit with POST, it goes into the POST array.  $_REQUEST is essentially equal to `$_REQUEST = $_POST + $_GET + $_COOKIE` being executed at the beginning of the script.  It's better almost always to always pick the most specific one, and there's rarely a case where picking $_REQUEST is the right way to go about things.